# getAdapterPosition somtimes returns wrong value

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create an adapter for a RecyclerView, where each view contains some information and two buttons, one for removing the view and one for updating the information. I set the listener as follows, and I get the actions to work as I want to (i.e. the `removeRecepie` and `chooseNewRandomRecepie` does what I want them to do).

However, sometimes, seemingly randomly, the getAdapterPosition sends the incorrect position. Thus the removal or updating happens to the incorrect view (I have tested the output of `getAdapterPosition`, and the output is consistent with the view that changes, i.e. the wrong one). I have written the `setListener` as follows:

```
    void setListener(View view){
        Button removeButton = view.findViewById(R.id.remove_button);
        removeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                removeRecepie(getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
        Button newRandomButton = view.findViewById(R.id.new_random);
        newRandomButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                chooseNewRandomRecepie(getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
    }
```

I would be really grateful for any help, or pointers to help. Please let me know if there is any further information I can include to help you help me :)

Comment: `getAdapterPosition` can return -1 in some cases(You should check for it before calling anything with it) but never  wrong position . There is probably some inconsistent data in your dataset when you adding or removing elements ..

Comment: when you add or remove item from adapter may be change couner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be use `onBindViewHolder`.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.removeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                removeRecepie(position);
            }
        });
        holder.removeButton.SetOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                chooseNewRandomRecepie(position);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        Button removeButton;
        Button newRandomButton;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            removeButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.removebutton);
            newRandomButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.newRandomButton);
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, it's not necessary to do setup clicklistener in the `onBindViewHolder` method.

Comment: The `setListener` method is called for the holder inside onBindViewHolder (sorry for not specifying this earlier). However, changing `removeButton` and `newRandomButton` to fields and instantiating them in the viewHolder constructor seems to be doing the trick (as in this answer). Does anyone have any idea why this could be?